# Working with python dictionary notation

Tags: python

I'm working on a program where the user inputs 3 values (one of which is in dictionary notation form).. but I'm having trouble finding out how to work with this special notation.

The user input will look like this:

```
{'X':'X+YF','Y':'FX-Y'}
```

which I store in a variable `p`. I know that with `p.keys()` I get `['X', 'Y']` and with `p.values()` I get `['X+YF', 'FX-Y']`.

How can I relate `'X'` to `'X+YF'` to say, if the value of the first key in `p` is `'X'`, store `'X+YF'` in a var, and if the value of the second key in `p` is `'Y'`, store `'FX-Y'` in a var?

---

Is something like this also possible with the same approach stated in the answers below?

```
 If x is found in some string :
   swap out the X with the value p['X']
```

Comment: A dictionary (`p`) has no "first key" or "second key".  The keys have no order `p['X']`, however, is the value associated with the key `'X'`.  Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: "Is something like this also possible"?  What do think `X in aString = p['X']` means?  What's it supposed to do?  It's probably "possible" but that pseudo-code is so obscure as to make it difficult to answer.

Comment: Sorry for the obscurity. I meant: if x is found in some string (aString) then swap out the X with the value p['X']

Comment: `for x in aString` guarantees that `x` is absolutely found in the string.  Guarantees.  Please fix that snippet of code.

Comment: Yes, I know. The for loop will run if & only if X is in the string.

Comment: "The for loop will run if & only if X is in the string".  Close.  But too complex.  The for loop provides values of `x` which are simply the individual characters selected from the string.   Please **fix** the code snippet.  It's very confusing and unhelpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking how to get the value associated to a particular key? You can acess a value by putting its key in square brackets:

```
myDict = {'X':'X+YF','Y':'FX-Y'}
myXVal = myDict['X']
myYVal = myDict['Y']
print myXVal, myYVal
```

output:

```
X+YF FX-Y
```

If you want to have different behavior based on which keys exist in the dict, you can use `in`:

```
if 'X' in myDict:
    #do some stuff with myDict['X'] here...
```

Edit in response to OP's edit:
My psychic debugging powers tells me that you're trying to implement an [L System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system). You need to replace all instances of 'X' with 'X+YF', and all instances of 'Y' with 'FX-Y'. I would implement the function like this:

```
#path is the string that you want to do replacements in.
#replacementDict is the dict containing the key-value pairs mentioned in your post.
def iterateLSystem(path, replacementDict):
    #strings aren't mutable, so we make a mutable list version of path
    listPath = list(path)
    for i in range(len(listPath)):
        currentChar = listPath[i]
        if currentChar in replacementDict:
            listPath[i] = replacementDict[currentChar]
    #glob listPath back into a single string
    return "".join(listPath)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. Is it also possible to do something like this? [I edited my post with the new question]

Comment: @Michele: somewhat, see my edited answer. It's a little tricker than your pseudocode because strings can't be mutated the way you want.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your time.. and your psychic debugging powers. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can walk over the dictionary using its `.items()` method:

```
for key, value in p.items():
    print key, value
# X X+YF
# Y FX-Y
# …
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.items()` or `.iteritems()` to walk through the pairs:

```
>>> p = {'X':'X+YF','Y':'FX-Y'}
>>> for k, v in p.iteritems():
...     print k, v
... 
Y FX-Y
X X+YF
```

If you want to check the existence of some key, use `in` keyword:

```
>>> 'X' in p
True
>>> if 'Y' in p:
...     print p['Y']
... 
FX-Y
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = {'X':'X+YF','Y':'FX-Y'}
var = p['X']
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: actually I'm not sure if that's what I need. The number of keys in the dictionary might be more than 2, so I wanted to loop through and get the first key value (in the example it would be 'X') and store that into a var, and then get the value associated with it and store that into a var, until I have checked each value.

Comment: The reason for this is that I can't say var = p['X'] because I don't know if the key will be an 'X' in every case. So I need a way of getting the key value and storing it, then getting the value associated with it and storing it seperately

Comment: @Michele: but p is already storing the keys and values. Is there some particular reason you want to store them separately?

Comment: Ideally I would like to take apart the dictionary that the user entered and perform conditional checks. Ex: if [any key value in dictionary] is 'X', do stuff to it's associated value: 'X+XY'.

Comment: @Michele, you can do conditional behavior with "if 'X' in myDict:"